# How do you update the last row in a table using SQL in ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I decided to rephrase my question to make it a bit easier.
I have a form  with three fields

```
<form class="contact_form" action="divProgramProcess.asp" method="post" name="contact_form">
Couch: <input type="text"  name="Couch_Current" id="Couch_Current" />
<br/>
Available:  
<input type="text"  name="Available_Current" id="Available_Current"  />
<br/>
Shipment:
<input type="text" name="Shipment_Current" id="Shipment_Current" />   
<input type="submit" value="submit" ></form>
```

The form calls the following code divProgramProcess.asp (shown below)

```
<%  
divrec = request.QueryString("div")
Set rstest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rstest.locktype = adLockOptimistic sql = "SELECT top 1 * FROM CensusFacility_Records WHERE  division_program = 'Division 1' and jmsday ='Sun' order by JMSUpdateDateTime desc "
rstest.Open sql, db
%>

<%
Shipment_Current = request.form("Shipment_Current")
Couch_Current = request.form("Couch_Current")
Available_Current = request.form("Available_Current")

rstest.fields("Shipment") = Shipment_Current
rstest.fields("Couch") = Couch_Current
rstest.fields("Available") = Available_Current
rstest.update
Response.Redirect("chooseScreen.asp")
%>
```

Now keep in mind that the column 'JMSUpdateDateTime" is a date field and there are multiple records of 'Division 1" under the division_program column name.
I'm trying to update the last row in my SQL table but everytime I run this script I only update the first record with "Division 1" not the last record. To put it simply: There are 10 records that contain Division 1. All of them have date timestamp columns. How can I update the last record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM CensusFacility_Records WHERE  division_program = 'Division 1' 
and jmsday ='Sun' and JMSUpdateDateTime = (SELECT MAX(JMSUpdateDateTime) 
FROM CensusFacility_Records WHERE  division_program = 'Division 1' and jmsday ='Sun')"
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I run your query I get the following error. "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record. "

Answer (score 2):

Instead of updating via recordset, run an actual UPDATE Statement. Basicaly you will need 2 steps:

1. Run your `SELECT TOP 1 ...` query, but retreive just a primary key/identity field from the table (not " * ") and save it into some temp variable
2. Run actual SQL `"UPDATE CensusFacility_Records SET Shipment = ... WHERE TABLE_ID = " & yourTempVariable`

(Best would be to create a parametrized query instead of adding parameters to query string inline). This way you're guaranteed to really update specific record.